# how to make WPF control refresh its status once the Status of a test case is changed in the c/c++ method

Tags: c#, c++, wpf

I have defined a class as below:

```
public class TestCase
{
    int status;
    public int Status
    {
        get
        {
            return status;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value != status)
            {
                status = value;
                RaisePropertyChange("Status");
            }
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

And I have bind a WPF control to this Status property. When user click a button, it will PInvoke an API defined in a C++ dll. In this API, it will change the value of Status, like from NotExecuted->Executing->Passed/Failed. 
The API is as below:

```
void RunTest(TestCase* tc); // here, TestCase is a C++ struct.
```

I call it like:

```
[DllImport(dllFilePath, EntryPoint = "RunTest", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
public extern static bool RunTest(ref TestCase oneCase);
...
RunTest(ref tc);
```

My question is how to make WPF control refresh its status once the Status of a test case is changed in the c/c++ method

Comment: This sounds a bit strange to me. Anyways, why not go for some form of observer pattern, I am not good enough to C++ to tell you have, but shouldn't that be do able

Comment: C/C++ is not a language. I see that you are using C++ in the rest of your question. I assume that C is not used at all i.e. safe to remove?

Comment: Depending on how much control you have over the c++ code you could have it update a text file, and then in your C# use a FileSystemWatcher to detect when the file changes. Then when the c++ changes the file you can have your C# code update your WPF control. A little round about, but it would be easy to set up.